# Change console size

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, compiling, configuration

I'm trying to run linux kernel inside VMware from iso image compiled from sources.
At the current moment I'm trying to start initramfs but for some reasons it crashes. My problem is I cannot know why because of size of TTY.
I changed CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE_ROWS from 25 to 60 in my .config file but it didn't make any changes.
What else can I do?

Comment: Try passing `vga=ask` as a kernel argument

Comment: Sorry for question but how can I pass a kernel argument? I boot kernel directly through iso image that I got from `make isoimage`

Answer (score 3):

When troubleshooting early boot issues on VMware, it might be useful to configure the kernel to use a serial port as a console. You'll need the kernel boot options for that: in your case, the only ways to specify them might be via the `CONFIG_CMDLINE` kernel configuration option, or with the `FDARGS="..."` environment variable during the kernel build, similar to using `FDINITRD=` to specify your initramfs file when using `make isoimage`.

In your case, that would probably have to be by adding the options `console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0`, then configuring VMware to save any output to virtual COM1 serial port into a file. This way, you should get the full list of Linux kernel boot messages into a file.

(The `console=tty0` part makes sure you'll also get console output to the VMware console window; without it, the console output would go to the serial port *only*, leaving the VGA virtual display completely unused.)

To successfully use serial ports like this, you'll also need the kernel configuration options `CONFIG_SERIAL_8250=y` and `CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_CONSOLE=y`.

---

I think `CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE_ROWS` and `CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE_COLUMNS` only affect the virtual "dummy" console device, that is only in effect until the real console device driver takes over. The real console driver will set the rows/columns according to the display mode used on the console.

The [comment at the beginning of `drivers/video/console/dummycon.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/video/console/dummycon.c?h=v5.10.6) seems to confirm this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-only
/*
 *  linux/drivers/video/dummycon.c -- A dummy console driver
 *
 *  To be used if there's no other console driver (e.g. for plain VGA text)
 *  available, usually until fbcon takes console over.
 */
```

Also, the [`drivers/video/console/vgacon.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/video/console/vgacon.c?h=v5.10.6) (that is, the actual VGA console text mode driver) does not use `CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE_ROWS` at all.

If you use the classic VGA text console (the `vgacon.c` mentioned above, configured with `CONFIG_VGA_CONSOLE=y`), then the kernel boot option `vga=ask` (and once you've seen the resulting output and picked a suitable (S)VGA text mode number, `vga=<mode number>`) as suggested by Artem S. Tashkinov in the question comments would be appropriate.

Modern Linux distributions use instead `CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y` and will usually load an appropriate frame buffer device driver from initramfs, because it will higher-resolution modes than plain old VGA. But since you're troubleshooting an early boot problem, you would need to have it in the kernel to get output to a display (VMware display window). If you're booting the VM using traditional BIOS style (which is what `make isoimage` probably does), the driver in question would be `CONFIG_FB_VESA=y`; if you're using UEFI-style boot, `CONFIG_FB_EFI=y` would be a good idea.

The `CONFIG_FB_VESA` also uses the `vga=` boot option to set the initial console display resolution for legacy reasons, but the modes may not be listed with `vga=ask`; see [Documentation/fb/vesafb.rst here](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/fb/vesafb.rst) or in the kernel source code tree for more info and a list of modes to choose from.

If using UEFI (or basically any other framebuffer console driver than `CONFIG_FB_VESA`), you would need to specify the desired display mode using boot parameter `video=` instead; see [`Documentation/fb/modedb.rst` in the kernel source tree](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/fb/modedb.rst) for the full details.

In a nutshell, the video mode selection parameter for `CONFIG_FB_EFI` (similar to any non-VESA framebuffer console, really) might look like this:

```
video=efifb:1280x1024@60
```

This will automatically choose a suitable text resolution for the video mode.